# Is there an equivalent to "fstrim -av" for ZFS on Linux (ZoL)

Tags: zfs

I'm looking to periodically trim all drives via a script, My servers have a mix of ext4 and zfs.

I currently use fstrim -av for the mounted etx4 volumes but what's the equivalent command for ZoL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is. As of ZoL 0.8.x, you can do the following:

```
zpool trim poolname
```

Or you can:

```
zpool set autotrim=on poolname
```

to have it happen as blocks get deallocated.

Comment: Thank you. To get trim status after running zpool trim poolname you can use zpool status poolname. Also the parameters for zpool trim are:
       zpool trim [-d] [-r <rate>] [-c | -s] <pool> [<device> ...]